# How could I use Unix gVim settings on Windows?

Tags: windows, vim, setting

I have the following settings on Unix:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py
\ set tabstop=4
\ set softtabstop=4
\ set shiftwidth=4
\ set textwidth=79
\ set expandtab
\ set autoindent
\ set fileformat=unix

au BufNewFile,BufRead *.js, *.html, *.css
\ set tabstop=2
\ set softtabstop=2
\ set shiftwidth=2
```

But I didn't manage to use it on Windows 7. Could anyone please tell me how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings must be modified before you migrate it from Unix to Windows as follows:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py
\ set tabstop=4
\ softtabstop=4
\ shiftwidth=4
\ textwidth=79
\ expandtab
\ autoindent
\ fileformat=unix


au BufNewFile,BufRead *.html
\ set tabstop=2
\ softtabstop=2
\ shiftwidth=2

au BufNewFile,BufRead *.css
\ set tabstop=2
\ softtabstop=2
\ shiftwidth=2

au BufNewFile,BufRead *.js
\ set tabstop=2
\ softtabstop=2
\ shiftwidth=2
```

Next, save it to `$VIMRUNTIME/XXX.vim` (where `XXX` is a placeholder), and then source it in your `_vimrc` file.